# LSTM/RNN Predicting cosine from sine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tflearn

I am trying to code a simple LSTM/RNN. Given a `sine` input, can I predict the `cosine` signal?

While running my code, I can accurately predict next value of `sine` given historical `sine` values; but I am unable to accurately predict the next value of `cosine` given historical `sine` values.

I heavily borrowed from this [following code example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), which is used to predict the next character from the alphabet.

Since I am using a LSTM/RNN, I define `windows` (of length `seq_length`) of sequence input data corresponding to an output data point.

For example,

> Input Sequence -> Output Sequence
>
> [ 0. , 0.00314198, 0.00628393, 0.00942582, 0.01256761] -> 1.0

In the above sample sequence, `sin(0)` is 0, and then we have the `sine` values for the next 4 points. These values have an associated `cos(0)`.

Corresponding code,

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

time_points = np.linspace(0, 8*np.pi, 8000)

seq_length = 5
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, len(time_points) - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = np.sin(time_points)[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = np.cos(time_points)[i]
    dataX.append([seq_in])
    dataY.append(seq_out)

X = np.reshape(dataX, (len(dataX), seq_length, 1)) #numpy as np
y = np.reshape(dataY, (len(dataY), 1))
```

LSTM Keras code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))


model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X[:6000], y[:6000], epochs=20, batch_size=10, verbose=2, validation_split=0.3)
```

The following figure shows the prediction and the ground truth, when we try to learn cosine from sequential sine data.

[image]

However, if we were to learn sine using sequential sine data (i.e. have `seq_out = np.sin(time_points)[i]`), the prediction is accurate as shown below.

[image]

I was wondering what could be going wrong.

Or, how can I get a more accurate prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. It was a matter of increasing the number of epochs and fiddling with the batch size. For example, here is the prediction for #epochs = 200, batch size = 10.

[image]